# Regex match a specific filename format Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match a filename format which is `filename_nrows_ncols`. I came up with `(_[\d]+_[\d]+)$` and tested it in Rubular and it works there. http://www.rubular.com/r/W7DKNhmpMV
But when I'm trying to assugn the match to a variable in my perl code, I get `Use of uninitialized value...` error. What's wrong with my regex? Thanks in adv.

```
$match =~ /(_[\d]+_[\d]+)$/;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say, but I'd imagine it should look something like this:

```
if ($filename =~ /(\d+_\d+)$/) {
  # Do something
}
```

By the way the [] around [\d] isn't necessary in this case.  If you had something other than the \d within it, it would be.

-- EDIT --

I think I see what's wrong.  You want the results of the regex to go into $match.  If that's the case, assuming your filename is in the default variable, then you probably want this:

```
my ($match) = /(\d+_\d+)$/;
```

or if it's in another variable

```
my ($match) = $filename =~ /(\d+_\d+)$/;
```

The error, by the way, only appears to be a warning from "use warnings" or -W.  It's a good one, though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide the entire line of code that's causing that error. The regular expression itself looks fine (although you may be better off with something like `^(.+)_(\d+)_(\d+)$` if you plan on doing anything with the filename, nrows, or ncols (which would then be stored in `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` respectively).

Comment: I tested `^(.+)_(\d+)_(\d+)$` in Rubular. It does match the whole string but so does `^(.+)`. So how would it store in `$1`, `$2` and `$3`?

Comment: Parentheses function as grouping operators and the matched text for each group is accessible "automagically" in $1, $2, etc.